# Riemann Integration Problem

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f$ be a continuous function on $[0,1]$ satisfying $$\int_0^1f(x)\,dx = 0$$

and $$\int_0^1xf(x)\,dx = 0.$$ Show that there exists $a$,$b$ in $[0,1]$ with $a < b$, 
such that $f(a) = 0 =f(b)$.
Existence of one point is clear to me but I cannot prove the existence of the other one.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: See meta: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/how-do-i-accept-an-answer)

Comment: Please read [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/3286/8271)

Comment: You accept an answer by clicking on the check mark $\sqrt{}$ below the vertical arrows used for voting.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If there was only one root $a$, unless $f$ is identically zero $f$ would have to change signs at $a$ in order for $\displaystyle\int^1_0 f(x) dx=0$ to hold. Hence $(x-a)f(x)$ doesn't change sign and is not identically zero, so $\displaystyle\int^1_0 (x-a) f(x) \neq 0,$ contradicting the hypothesis.

Comment: Thank you very much Ragib for such a nice proof